Angular 17 ngIf accepts boolean only?
I had a working Angular app and now it seems that there is a breaking change and *ngIf accepts only boolean values, not casting falsy/truthy values to boolean.
However, I could not find anything in docs, nor with internet search, so, it seems if I were the only one experiencing this. But then I have no idea how/why this is happening.
<pre><code>{{ arr?.length }}</code></pre>

<pre *ngIf="arr?.length">has length (value)</pre>
<pre *ngIf="!!arr?.length">has length (bool)</pre>
<pre *ngIf="!arr?.length">has no length (bool)</pre>



What was the previous version? React does this too, and it is kind of annoying but if you've upgraded and there were changes, then you'll need to coerce to Boolean in the template

Can you provide a stackblitz repro ? I couldn't acchieve the same result.

The previous version was using component based Accordion from NgBootstrap but they removed that from v16 and I had to refactor all of them. This new one seems too complicated to me, but they probably had the reason to it like this.
Thank all of you for quick responses!

Turned out it wasn't Angular itself but it was within an NgBootstrap Accordion component and I did not wrapped my content with <ng-template> inside ngbAccordionBody.
wrong:
...
<div ngbAccordionBody>
    <pre *ngIf="arr?.length">has length (value)</pre>
</div>

correct:
...
<div ngbAccordionBody>
  <ng-template>
    <pre *ngIf="arr?.length">has length (value)</pre>
  </ng-template>
</div>

This seems over-engineered to me, but that's out of scope. Finally, it works.
